# Iframe: keep parent and iframe jquery librarys from conflicting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, conflict

Ok here's the problem in a nut shell:

I'm building a landing page editor and i'm loading user created templates into an iframe on the editor page.  The parent has jquery and ui loaded on it because the tools include drag and drop.  I'm dragging and dropping boxes and such into the iframe and then crawling the iframe and making the resulting dropped elements draggable within the iframe.

So to be clear i have everything working perfectly you can drag and resize and everything from parent window into iframe.  HOWEVER there is a conflict if the template that is loaded into the editor already has jquery in it.

I need the templates loaded into the editor be be able to have jquery if they need them because some templates might have a jquery slider etc...

My first question is ... if the parent "editor" page already has jquery on it and i'm crawling the iframe and manipulating content, is jquery already loaded in the iframe?  in other words if someone had a jquery slider in their template could i just make sure the iframe doesn't load jquery and then the slider would still work because the parent already has it? If this is the case and I don't need them twice than is there an easy to way crawl the contents of an iframe and take out a script tag that is loading jquery ????

My second question is ... is there a "no conflict" rule or something that i can call on jquery so it doesn't conflict if there are two?

My third question is am i screwed :(?

Please help me!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, did you find a solution to this? In my case it is phpfox using jquery 1.8 and my app in the iframe is using jquery 1.11. using jquery in the parent gives me a SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object HTMLDocument]' is not a valid selector. after removing the frame tag everything works ...

Answer (score -1):

The conflict can`t happen instead iframes can be use to remove conflicts , so if you have an iframe with jquery and the parent of iframe also have a jquery than this will never conflict, may be there are some other issues in your code .

And for loading scripts dynamically you can use `$.getScript("name.js")`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply i'm not so sure you're right .... the iframe and parent are on the same domain and i know that loading jquery in the iframe causes a conflict as soon as i remove it everything works perfectly.